# full screen view of flex application

Tags: apache-flex

I want full screen view(through code,without pressing F11) of my flex application.Can you please help me?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=flex+full+screen ?

Answer (score 5):

From [Flex Examples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/07/creating-full-screen-flex-applications/).

The line you're interested in is probably this:

```
Application.application.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

This is what the movie players and such use to get full screen.